# How can i show Google Adsense Ads in my Wordpress Site Homepage, in between posts Grid layout, not inside posts

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, adsense

How can I show "Google Ad-sense Ads" in my "WordPress" Site "Homepage", in between posts Grid layout? not inside posts. For Homepage King-composer plugin is used and want to show 'Google Ads' after specific posts only as may ads as possible. Please Help me with this. I tried many ways and used some plugins also. but nothing works.

Attaching Code file which we want to code to display Google ads.. and also attaching Homepage screenshot where I want to show ads in between the grid layout posts, not inside posts... Help me, please.

```
    <?php
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'ads_source'        => 'by_choice',
    'topads'            => 'no',
    'post_ids'          => '',
    'post_number'       => '6',
    'category_ids'      => '',
    'location_ids'      => '',
    'type'              => '',
    'orderby'           => '',
    'order'             => '',
    'style'             => 'grid',
    'slider'            => 'no',
    'visible_items'     => '',
    'autoplay_speed'    => '',
    'double_row'        => '',
    'items_in_row'      => '4'
), $atts ) );

if( $ads_source == 'by_choice' ){
    $args = array(
        'post__in' => explode( ',', $post_ids ),
        'orderby'  => 'post__in'
    );
}
else{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $post_number,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,
        'order'          => $order,
    );

    if( $topads == 'yes' ){
        $args['post__in'] = adifier_topads_ids_list();
    }

    if( !empty( $category_ids ) ){
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'advert-category',
                'terms'     => explode( ',', $category_ids )
            )
        );
    }

    if( !empty( $location_ids ) ){
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'advert-location',
                'terms'     => explode( ',', $location_ids )
            )
        );
    }   
}
if( !empty( $type ) ){
    $args['type'] = $type;
}

$args['post_status'] = 'publish';
$adverts = new Adifier_Advert_Query( $args );
if( $adverts->have_posts() ){
    if( $style == 'big_slider' ){
        ?>
        <div class="adverts-big-slider owl-carousel">
            <?php
            while( $adverts->have_posts() ){
                $adverts->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="white-block hover-shadow">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="advert-media">
                        <?php adifier_get_advert_image('adifier-single-slider') ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="white-block-content">
                        <?php include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/advert-boxes/top-meta.php' ) ) ?>

                        <?php include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/advert-boxes/title.php' ) ) ?>

                        <?php include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/advert-boxes/bottom-meta.php' ) ) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else{
        $max = $double_row == 'yes' ? 2 : 1;
        $counter = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="adverts-list clearfix <?php echo  $slider == 'yes' ? esc_attr( 'adverts-slider owl-carousel' ) : esc_attr( 'af-items-'.$items_in_row ) ?>" data-visibleitems="<?php echo esc_attr( $visible_items ) ?>" data-autoplay="<?php echo esc_attr( $autoplay_speed ) ?>">
            <div class="af-item-wrap">
            <?php
            while( $adverts->have_posts() ){
                $adverts->the_post();
                if( $max == $counter ){
                    ?>
                    </div><div class="af-item-wrap">
                    <?php
                    $counter = 0;
                }
                $counter++;
                if( $style == 'list' ){
                    $limit = 80;
                }
                include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/advert-boxes/'.$style.'.php' ) );
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

My Home Page image screenshot where I want to show Google ads in between Grid Layout :

[image]